# php curl get html and js render

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, curl

php curl only get the source code of a html page without executing the js script. I need for my website to get the source code with all the javascript already executed. I use ajax and I can't add more js in the page because script stay when I load another page. I find spiderMonkey but it can't fix my problem.

Is there something in php which do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. Not from PHP directly.

If you have control over the server you could install [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) and have it execute the code since it basically provides you with a headless browser that can do what you want.